# how to get trends from twitter about a specific location

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get the twitter trends for a specific location say "Bristol" from UK for my application.

Problem is that right now we can get the Trends for only countries and some cities in US as mentioned in twitter API. But i'm just wondering how the site like

http://trendsmap.com/local/gb/bristol

is getting the trends in most of the countries and cities even though they were not listed in twitter trends api.

Please help in figuring out this

Regards,
Sukumar

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616017/getting-top-twitter-trends-by-country/17107785#17107785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the documentation here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/trends/%3awoeid)

Comment: I tried using WOEID of bristol(Bristol WOEID=13963) using below but it's giving Page not found error
http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/13963.xml

Comment: I would imagine it's because it doesn't store trends for Bristol. I tried London and got this: http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/44418.json

Answer (score 2):

I put together a nice JS fiddle that should answer all your questions when it comes to dealing with the Twitter API. The webapp grabs the trending locales, and allows you to drill down to the trending topics, and then see the Tweets within.

I also included a standard Twitter search submission box, so in a weird way, this is a barebones Tweetdeck client for you to examine.  Also, to push the adaption of the new Jquery libraries, I have used 1.91 which utilities the new live.bind click event syntax.

Enjoy

http://jsfiddle.net/jdrefahl/5M3Gn/

```
function searchTwitter(query) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + jQuery.param(query),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        var tweets = $('#tweets');
        tweets.html('');
        for (res in data['results']) {
            tweets.append('<div>' + data['results'][res]['from_user'] + ' wrote: <p>' + data['results'][res]['text'] + '</p></div><br />');
        }
    }
});
```

}

$(document).ready(function () {

```
function getTrendsByID(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/' + id + '.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data[0].trends, function (i) {
            });
        }
    });
};

function getLocales() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/available.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            var locales = $('ul#locales');
            locales.html('');
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                localeID[i] = data[i].woeid;
                $('ul#locales').append('<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });

};

function getTrends(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/' + id + '.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            var trends = $('ul#currentTrends');
            trends.html('');
            $.each(data[0].trends, function (i) {
                $('ul#currentTrends').append('<li>' + data[0].trends[i].name + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
};

// Event Handlers
$(document).on("click", "#locales li", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var localesHdr = $('#currentTrendsCont h3');
    var tweets = $('#tweets');
    var trendsHdr = $('#tweetsCont h3');
    trendsHdr.html('');
    tweets.html('');
    localesHdr.html('');
    $('#currentTrendsCont h3').html($this.text());
    getTrends(localeID[$this.index()]);
});

$(document).on("click", "#currentTrends li", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var trendsHdr = $('#tweetsCont h3');
    trendsHdr.html('');
    $('#tweetsCont h3').html($this.text());
    var params = {
        q: $this.text(),
        rpp: 10
    };
    searchTwitter(params);
});

$('#submit').click(function () {
    var trendsHdr = $('#tweetsCont h3');
    var trends = $('#currentTrends');
    var local = $('#currentTrendsCont h3');
    local.html('');
    trendsHdr.html('');
    trends.html('');
    $('#tweetsCont h3').html('search query: '+$('#query').val());
    var params = {
        q: $('#query').val(),
        rpp: 10
    };
    searchTwitter(params);
});

// Globals
var localeID = new Array();

// Init!
getLocales();
```

});

Comment: Is it possible to get lowest trending tweet from twitter