# Getting top twitter trends by country

Tags: twitter

I know how to get trends using API, but i want it by country and top 10.

How can I ? Is that possible?

Tried this one but not working

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json?count=50
```

Comment: These methods doesn't work anymore. API 1 is obsolete and you have to authenticate to use API 1.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can.

First, figure out [which countries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/:woeid) you want to get data for.

Calling

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/available
```

Will give you a list of all the countries Twitter has trends for.

Suppose you want the trends for the UK.  The above tells us that the WOEID is 23424975.

To get the [top ten trends](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/available) for the UK, call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424975.json
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore. API 1 is obsolete.

Answer (score 11):

Note that Twitter API v1 is no longer functional. [Read announcement](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-date-extended-to-june-11)
So you should use Twitter API 1.1.

REST method is this: [GET trends/place](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place)

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place
```

You should authenticate with access tokens to reach this data.

Answer (score 1):

you need to figure out the woeids first use this tool here http://sigizmund.info/woeidinfo/ and then it becomes as easy as a simple function

```
function get_trends($woeid){
        return json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/".$woeid.".json?exclude=hashtags", true), false); 
    }
```

Here you go, I wrote a simple sample script for you. Check It Out Here [Twitter Trends Getter](http://clients.nishantarora.in/projects/twitter_trends/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can we get trends from multiple $woeid in single request?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a 'bit' late to the party on this one but you can use:

## npm i twit --save

then,

```js
const Twit = require('twit');
const config = require('./config');
const T = new Twit(config);
const params = {
 id: '23424829',
 id: '23424975',
 id: '23424977'
 // count: 3
};

T.get('trends/place', params, gotData, limit);

function gotData(err, data, response) {
 var tweets = data;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(tweets, undefined, 2));
}
```